# How to connect to Cosmos MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I created a local Cosmos instance and set up a MongoDb for my c# application based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

When trying to get data however, it just seems to hang forever

It's not clear as to what my connection string should contain, but I've populated it with this:

```
"ClientDataRepositoryConfiguration": {
    "CollectionName": "ClientData",
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5%2FR%2Bob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM%2B4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw%2FJw%3D%3D@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true",
    "DatabaseName": "ClientData"
 },
```

Is anyone able to advise whether I have entered this correctly?

This is what my cosmos looks like:

[image]

Where I have a Database called ClientData, which has a container called ClientData.

---

**Controller Endpoint**

```
[HttpGet("Test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestGet()
{
    // I can hit breakpoint here, it hangs when waiting for `GetallAsync`
    var result = await _clientDataRepository.GetAllAsync();
    return Json(result); 
}
```

**Repository**

```
internal sealed class ClientDataRepository : IClientDataRepository
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<ClientData> _clientDatas;

    public ClientDataRepository(
        IClientDataRepositoryConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(configuration.ConnectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(configuration.DatabaseName);

        _clientDatas = database.GetCollection<ClientData>(configuration.CollectionName);
    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<ClientData>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
        => await _clientDatas
            .Find(i => true)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Sajeetharan It just times out when trying to get data from mongo

Comment: did you try debugging and see if the client is created? can you post the code as welll?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes, the client is definitely created and it tries to fetch the data. Will post code in a sec

Comment: @Sajeetharan I added code for my controller and repo

Comment: which method is failing? as i see there are 2

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't know what you mean? There is only one method call, and its `GetAllAsync`. This runs fine, but I never get my values returned in the controller (hangs on await)

Comment: @Sajeetharan So `Json(result)` is never hit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223697/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-bassie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos Emulator does not support data explorer except for SQL API as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator). You probably have created collection using SQL API.

> You can develop applications using Azure Cosmos emulator with the SQL,
> Cassandra, MongoDB, Gremlin, and Table API accounts. Currently the
> data explorer in the emulator fully supports viewing SQL data only;
> the data created using MongoDB, Gremlin/Graph and Cassandra client
> applications it is not viewable at this time.

[image]

Either you can create you collection and database using code (not data explorer) or you can use `mongod` command from the [local mongodb installation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).

If you use `mongod` tool instead, Connection string should look like `mongodb://localhost:<port>` as mentioned in the [documentatio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-configuration-model). Default port 27017 for `mongod` tool.

```
"ClientDataRepositoryConfiguration": {
    "CollectionName": "ClientData",
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "ClientData"
 },
```

Another option is using [Azure Resource instead of local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-dotnet).

Comment: So you are saying there is no way for me to create a mongo database from the cosmos emulator data explorer?

Comment: Nice one, its confusing because when viewing data under `SQL API` it is displayed as a json object

Comment: SQL API also shows json as the data store is no-sql documents. SQL API does not mean SQL table :), it's more of SQL like syntax which can be used to query documents.